# What is the purpose of assets\www\deltas folder?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

This folder is huge (currently 15mb) and gets larger every time we do a build.

It has a load of guid named javascript files under `app.js\` and a load of guid named json files under `resources\css\myapp.css\`

The android app appears to work without it but it must have a purpose. Someone here said they thought it was to do with caching and updating that cache.

Not sure if it's being created by Sencha or cordova.

To build I use the lines:

```
sencha app refresh
sencha app build package
```

Comment: What is your build process? I have never seen this folder when using Cordova...

Comment: @MBillau have added, it might be actually caused by sencha touch

Comment: Hmmm yeah, `/delta/` is definitely something caused by the Sencha build process, not Cordova. Sorry I don't know enough about Sencha to help...

Comment: @MBillau no problem, that's helpful anyway thanks.

Comment: I have also faced this issue. As a solution I use to delete all the folders within "build" folder and then do the sencha build.